# On normal extension, a square root of discriminant is in field F?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

The probrem I have now is

> Let $F$ be a Field, and $f(X) = X^3+aX+b \in F[X]$ be a irreducible
> polynomial.
> Also, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in E$ ($E$ is the smallest splitting field of $f$) are roots of $f$, and $d$ is discriminant of $f$.
> Then, the followings are equivalent.
>
> - (1). $F(\alpha)/F$ is normal extension.
> - (2). A square root of $d$ is in $F(\alpha)$.
> - (3). A square root of $d$ is in $F$.

My approch are followings.

- $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ follows from $d = (\alpha-\beta)^2(\beta-\gamma)^2(\gamma-\alpha)^2$ and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in K(\alpha)$.
- $(3) \Rightarrow (2)$ follows from $\exists r \in F \subset F(\alpha)$ s.t. $d = r^2$.
- $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ Let $g(X) \in F(\alpha)[X]$ be a polynomial with $\beta$ and $\gamma$ as roots. Then, by (2),
  $$
  (\alpha-\beta)(\beta-\gamma)(\gamma-\alpha) = g(\alpha)(\gamma-\beta) \in F(\alpha)
  $$
  and $g(\alpha) \in F(\alpha)$. So, $\beta-\gamma \in F(\alpha)$. Also, $\beta+\gamma = -\alpha \in F(\alpha)$ by Vieta's formula. Therefore, $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$.

I want to prove $(1) \Rightarrow (3)$ or $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$ and $X^2-d \in F[X]$ is key to solve this in my thought, but I have come up with nothing.

Please some hints or solution.
Thankyou for your time!

Comment: Consider the degrees of $f(X)$ and $X^2-d$

Comment: Thank you for your hint! But I can't seem to come up with a solution right away, so I'll think about it...